# Denoise node in compositor changes the color of original image?

Tags: node-editor, compositing-nodes, texture-baking

I'm using denoise node in compositor to denoise a texture with baked lighting. It's working fine for the denoising part, but it changes the original color of the image. It's no long as saturated/vibrant anymore. Any workaround for that? Thanks[image]

original image

[image: Original image]

After denoise node

[image: After denoiser]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, the *Denoise* node isn't meant to be used with an imported image, but rather with *Render Layer* data, either from an image rendered in the software or pulled from a file saved in the .exr format.

For example, your .png image doesn't contain information for how many samples were used per pixel, which is useful information for the denoiser.  That doesn't stop you from using it if you want to, but the results may not be what you expect.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That explains why it's happening. Is there any way I can use my baked lighting texture directly with denoise node, just like a render?

Comment: I'm not sure about that, sorry.