# Is using the denoise compositing node to denoise FFmpeg video possible?

Tags: animation, compositing-nodes, denoise

If so how?
If it's not possible to do it with FFmpeg are there any other video formats that are compatible with the denoise compositing node?

Comment: FFMpeg is not a video format, it’s an encoding tool that blender uses to export video in various formats.

Comment: I guess I should've said a .mkv file instead.

Comment: You mean you have a noisy video, add it into the compositor as movie-clip, plug it into a denoise node and render through the composite output? Firstly: yes, the denoise node will denoise a plugged in image etc., but secondly: the noise has to be quite "clean", so more or less single pixels like fireflies etc. As soon as the noise is a bit blurry (and I guess it is if it's not a noisy animation but coming from some camera footage), then the denoise node will not recognize it as noise. And thirdly: if you mean artifacts caused by video compression, they will return when saved again as video.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/231376/110840